# WIN2k3 Network shares error?

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

On Windows Server 2003 several shared folders exist and have run just fine for well over a year.

These shares are also mapped network drives (not that this should make a difference).

When trying to view them:

```
c:\>net view \\SERVER_NAME
```

It kicks back with:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a nice article on this problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555644

Also, I've known firewall and router-rule changes have caused problems with allowing "net view" to work.

Comment: seems the right place to start.  my favorite is the "Windows Time Service Technical Reference" page, as clock sync most often causes theis.  Saddly there link results in: "Server Error in '/WINDOWSSERVER' Application."  I love microsoft!